# Access Imageview from fragment in toolbar

Tags: android, imageview, fragment, toolbar, android-fragmentactivity

I had added ImageView in toolbar and toolbar is in activity.How to access toolbar image in fragment.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textToolHeader"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="Header"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="@dimen/txt_18"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgToolIcon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/scale_10"
    android:src="@drawable/user"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

and my Fragment code is as below:

```
toolbar = (Toolbar) mView.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
imgToolIcon = (ImageView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.imgToolIcon);
imgToolIcon.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.print));
```

Please provide the solution for it.

Comment: Please post your `Toolbar` fragment code here aswell.

Comment: I am concerned that this question has been modified a number of times since you added a self-answer below. This would normally not be a problem, but since you've admitted to overwriting old questions with new ones in some of your other posts, I want to make sure that this is not also happening here. Are **all** of the answers below still valid for the new wording of the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I got solution of it which is as under :

```
ImageView imgToolIcon;
Toolbar toolbar;
TextView textToolHeader;

toolbar = (Toolbar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
imgToolIcon = (ImageView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.imgToolIcon);
imgToolIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.user);
```

This is exact solution which is helpful for me to set custom imageview in toolbar.

Answer (score 1):

**You can try like this**

```
imgToolIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.print);
```

**Instead of this**

```
imgToolIcon.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.print));
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't be a problem. As long as it's attached to an activity that fragment, you can do for instance:

```
ImageView iv = (ImageView) fragment.getView().findViewById(R.id.imgToolIcon);
```

Comment: what is fragment ? Please elaborate it

Comment: `fragment` is the Fragment that holds that toolbar.

Comment: which one? Are you sure the fragment has the layout with the toolbar in it?

Comment: Yes . But your code is not working . Thank you for effort i got solution

Comment: please add the answer so others can enjoy it as well!